# B-Spline Knot insertion using Boehm's algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, spline

I have a B-spline and I'm trying to implement Boehm's algorithm for inserting knots into the spline without changing its shape. For every two existing knots I have to add three new knots and delete the existing ones.

However I am having great difficulties understanding the papers on this algorithm and need some help to understand what I'm doing wrong.

This is what I'm trying to achieve: http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/cg/d3/knotInsert.html

The B-spline from this link is being evaluated and thee new knots (the orange ones) are constantly being generated between the current two knots which become gray at the time of evaluation between them.

I have read a lot of articles but the information in them all comes down to this: http://web.mit.edu/hyperbook/Patrikalakis-Maekawa-Cho/node18.html
And also this: https://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/B-spline/single-insertion.html

Basically, in order to find the new knot's position between two existing knots I have to first calculate the ratio based on t (which is the evaluation percent):
[image]

One of the first things that is unclear to me is the u parameter. From what I understand, this is the index of the current existing knot. However I don't understand why **t-ui** is divided by **ui+p-ui** What is the idea behind adding ui and then subtracting it? I'm sure that I'm definitely missing something here.

And then using this ratio (ai) find the position of the new knot:

[image]

My problem is not with the math - it is very simple math but its rather with the execution itself. All papers I read on the subject are very unclear (at least to me) on how the values in the equations are obtained and how they change in order to find each one of the newly created knots.

I wrote a method (C#) with which I'm trying to find exactly these three new orange knots from the interactive graphic from the first link and this is what I got:

```
        public Vector3[] InsertKnots(float percent)
    {
        //Percent [0-1]
        float t = 1 + percent * (points.Length - 1); //multiply percent to map the point count
        int ti = Mathf.FloorToInt(t); //this is the beginning index of the knot leg
        int degree = points.Length - 2; //Degree of the spline

        //Create the three new knots
        Vector3[] knots = new Vector3[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            int ui = ti + i;
            float ratio = (t - ui) / ((ui+degree)-ui); //finding ai
            knots[i] = (1f - ratio) * points[ui - 1] + ratio * points[ui]; //Finding the new knot's position 
        }
        return knots;
    }
```

Where points is a Vector3[] array (a class containing a float x, y and z properties).

Unfortunately, the result of this method looks like this:

[image]

Another major thing that I don't understand is what I have to do exactly in order to find the tree orange points. Do I have to run a for-loop (like I'm doing now)?

I couldn't find any code examples for this algorithm so I'm pretty much lost at this point.

Comment: I don't understand any of this, but `u(i+p) - ui` is fundamentally different from `ui + p - ui`.

Comment: @Corak - more correctly that should be u(i+p) - u(i). This question may be more appropriate for https://math.stackexchange.com to explain the algorithm

Comment: @PaulF - right. One of the examples (the mtu.edu link): if `i = 5` and `p = 3` you should have `u(5+3) - u(5)`, which is `u(8) - u(5)`.

Comment: @PaulF Ah yes, you are correct! (i + p) forms the index - this explains a lot. So that means that we are looking at the knot span values. But then the question is what is that knot span value. You are right, I should have posted this question on Math.